# .net WCF - CXF/WSS4j interoperability

Tags: wcf, cxf, ws-security

I would like to consume a CXF web-service from a .net c# client. We are currently working with java-to-java requests and we protect SOAP envelopes through ws-security (WSS4J library).

My question is: how can I implement a C# WS-client which produces the same SOAP requests as the following client-side java code?

```
//doc is the original SOAP envelope to process with WSS4J
WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();
secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);

//add username token with password digest
WSSecUsernameToken usrNameTok = new WSSecUsernameToken();
usrNameTok.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_DIGEST);
usrNameTok.setUserInfo("guest",psw_guest);
usrNameTok.prepare(doc);
usrNameTok.appendToHeader(secHeader);

//sign the envelope body with client key
WSSecSignature sign = new WSSecSignature();
sign.setUserInfo("clientx509v1", psw_clientx509v1);
sign.setKeyIdentifierType(WSConstants.BST_DIRECT_REFERENCE);

Document signedDoc = null;      
sign.prepare(doc, sigCrypto, secHeader);
signedDoc = sign.build(doc, sigCrypto, secHeader);

//encrypt envelope body with server public key
WSSecEncrypt encrypt = new WSSecEncrypt();
encrypt.setUserInfo("serverx509v1");

// build the encrypted SOAP part
String out = null;  
Document encryptedDoc = encrypt.build(signedDoc, encCrypto, secHeader);
return encryptedDoc;
```

Does anybody know where I could find a microsoft how-to or a .net working example?

================================ EDIT ====================================

Thank you Ladislav! I applied your suggestions and I came up with something like:

```
X509Certificate2 client_pk, server_cert;
client_pk = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\x509\clientKey.pem", "blablabla");
server_cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\x509\server-cert.pfx", "blablabla");

// Create the binding.
System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding myBinding = new WSHttpBinding();    
myBinding.TextEncoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
myBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;            
myBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
myBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite =                                          
            System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;

// Disable credential negotiation and the establishment of 
// a security context.
myBinding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
myBinding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;                

// Create the endpoint address. 
EndpointAddress ea =
    new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://bla.bla.bla"), 
            EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("issuer"));

// configure the username credentials on the channel factory 
UsernameClientCredentials credentials = new UsernameClientCredentials(new 
                                    UsernameInfo("superadmin", "secret"));

// Create the client. 
PersistenceClient client = new PersistenceClient(myBinding, ea);

client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = 
            System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

// replace ClientCredentials with UsernameClientCredentials
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ClientCredentials));
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(credentials);

// Specify a certificate to use for authenticating the client.
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = client_pk;

// Specify a default certificate for the service.
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = server_cert;

// Begin using the client.
client.Open();
clientProxyNetwork[] response = client.GetAllNetwork();
```

As a result I get (server-side) the following CXF exception:

```
 java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:421)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:133)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:112)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate  (PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117)
```

Therefore it seems a key jks->pem conversion problem... Or am I am missing something in the client-code above?

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but I'm trying to do similar thing right now, but unfortunately I can't. I've tried Your code, but I can't reference `UsernameClientCredentials` is this Your custom class? Basically I must create security header with UsernameToken, BinarySecurityToken and Signature

Comment: @Misiu Did you find any solution for this situation?

Comment: @Tagi sorry for the late reply. I created a custom class that implements `IClientMessageInspector` and basically it is creating the XML request by hand. Sadly I don't have access to the source code anymore.

Comment: @Misiu Did you create a complete request or only a security header? Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Tagi if I remember correctly I've only added the whole security header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in the end the solution is to encrypt and sign the whole username token. As for the interoperability, the ws addressing must be activated in cxf and a custom binding in c# is needed. The custom binding that did the trick is basically

```
AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement abe =
    (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.
CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.
WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
```

Wcf signs each ws addressing element, therefore the same must be done server side.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually pretty big problem because WCF [does not support UserNameToken Profile with Digested password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738565.aspx). I [needed it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/cda272c6-0443-45a6-ae08-844ee7478168) few months ago and we had to implement our own custom binding but that code is not ready for publishing. Fortunatelly [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx) describes other implementation and contains sample code with new `UserNameClientCredentials` class supporting digested password.

Btw. same security configuration should be possible with older API called WSE 3.0. It was replaced by WCF but still some WS-* stack configuration are much simpler with that API and old ASMX services.